# How do you restrict a webmin subdomain user to to just their home dir?

Tags: debian, ftp

I created a subdomain and a user with FTP access

but after logging in with that user it seams on the FTP the user can navigate up the dir structure to the actual domain

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the software and how its configured.  But, you can try this: in Webmin CP, go to Webmin > Servers > ProFTPd > Files & Directories. Under "Limit users to directories", select "home directory".  Apply the changes.